# Displaying data on a graph from a mongoDb database

Tags: python, mongodb, plot, pyqt, qt6

I encountered such a problem: on the graph, numbers from an array should be displayed gradually every 2 seconds, but for some reason, the entire array is displayed at once in 2 seconds. I also wanted to duplicate the graph data on a label, but the entire array is also displayed at once there. Does anyone know how to solve this?

I tried to show this situation in the screenshot.On the label, you can see that it simply cycles through the entire array, and on the chart too

[image]

Main program code

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from untdwdfd1 import Ui_MainWindow
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId
import threading
import time
import gridfs
# подключение к базе данных
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['resultbox']
collection = db['result']
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Подключаем обработчики событий
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
        self.pizdec = pg.PlotWidget(parent=self.page)
        self.pizdec.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 1191, 451))
        self.pizdec.setObjectName("pizdec")
        self.new_graph = pg.PlotWidget(parent=self.page_3)
        self.new_graph.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 1191, 451))
        self.new_graph.setObjectName("new_graph")

        # данные
        self.y1 = []
        self.x1 = list(range(len(self.y1)))
        self.y2 = []
        self.x2 = list(range(len(self.y2)))
        # линия
       # pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0))
        self.data_line1 = self.pizdec.plot(self.x1, self.y1, pen=pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0)))
        self.data_line2 = self.pizdec.plot(self.x2, self.y2, pen=pg.mkPen(color=(0, 255, 0)))

        self.is_fetching_data = False  # флаг, указывающий, выполняется ли передача данных в настоящее время
        self.is_graph_enabled = False  # флаг, указывающий, активирован ли график

        #таймер
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(2000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot_data)
        self.timer.start()
        self.data_line1.clear()
        self.data_line2.clear()# Очистить график
        self.is_graph_enabled = False  # Установить флаг, чтобы график не начинал показывать данные сразу после запуска


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_4_clicked(self):
        if self.is_fetching_data:
            return  # Если передача данных уже выполняется, ничего не делать
        self.is_fetching_data = True
        self.timer.start()
        self.is_graph_enabled = True


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_5_clicked(self):
        self.timer.stop()  # Остановить таймер
        self.is_fetching_data = False
        self.is_graph_enabled = False
        self.data_line1.clear()  # Очистить график
        self.data_line2.clear()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_3_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_2_clicked(self):
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(2)

#implementation with multithreading
    def update_plot_data(self):
        if not self.is_graph_enabled:
            return

        # Функция для обновления графика 1
        def update_plot_1():
            new_data1 = [value for doc in collection.find({'_id': ObjectId('640d94d8d9083914690976f5')}) for value in
                         doc['result']]
            self.y1.extend(new_data1)
            self.x1 = list(range(len(self.y1)))
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(0)

        # Функция для обновления графика 2
        def update_plot_2():
            new_data2 = [value for doc in collection.find({'_id': ObjectId('6416cd57ebd738fb8d1bb1d6')}) for value in
                         doc['result']]
            self.y2.extend(new_data2)
            self.x2 = list(range(len(self.y2)))
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(50)

        # Создаем два потока для обновления графиков

        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=update_plot_1)
        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=update_plot_2)

        # Запускаем потоки
        thread1.start()
        thread2.start()

        # Ждем завершения потоков
        thread1.join()
        thread2.join()
        self.data_line1.setData(self.x1, self.y1)
        self.data_line2.setData(self.x2, self.y2)
        #implementation without multithreading

        if self.y1:
            self.label_10.setText(str(self.y1))
        if self.y2:
            self.label_9.setText(str(self.y2))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Code from untdwdfd.py

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1495, 788)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 221, 761))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(51, 53, 56);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.frame)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 212, 261))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::hover {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::pressed {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(85, 0, 127);\n"
"    border: 3px solid\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::hover {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::pressed {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(85, 0, 127);\n"
"    border: 3px solid\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::hover {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::pressed {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(85, 0, 127);\n"
"    border: 3px solid\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.frame)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_14.setFont(font)
        self.label_14.setStyleSheet("\n"
"\n"
"background-color: rgb(26, 27, 28);\n"
"color:  rgb(184, 187, 192);")
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 0, 1281, 761))
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(26, 27, 28);")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.graph = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(parent=self.frame_3)
        self.graph.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1351, 741))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Serif")
        self.graph.setFont(font)
        self.graph.setObjectName("graph")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.page)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 630, 171, 101))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 2px solid;\n"
"    border-color:rgb(184, 187, 192);\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::hover {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::pressed {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(85, 0, 127);\n"
"    border: 3px solid\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(184, 187, 192);\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::hover {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton::pressed {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(85, 0, 127);\n"
"    border: 3px solid\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 590, 171, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(26, 27, 28);\n"
"color: rgb(184, 187, 192);\n"
"background-color: rgb(51, 53, 56);")
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 540, 261, 191))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(184, 187, 192);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 540, 261, 191))
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(184, 187, 192);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.graph.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_2)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 100, 281, 211))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 37, 39);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 100, 281, 211))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 37, 39);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 360, 281, 211))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 37, 39);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_2)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 350, 281, 211))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 37, 39);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_2)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 281, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(26, 27, 28);\n"
"color: rgb(184, 187, 192);\n"
"background-color: rgb(51, 53, 56);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.graph.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 100, 831, 401))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(80)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.graph.addWidget(self.page_3)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1495, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuw3rrewd = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent=self.menubar)
        self.menuw3rrewd.setObjectName("menuw3rrewd")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuw3rrewd.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.graph.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статический режим                  "))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Режим технического прогона"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Динамический режим                "))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "     Выбор режима"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Старт"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Стоп"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "         Управление "))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "   Наличие жидкостей в емкостях"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3 page"))
        self.menuw3rrewd.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "w3rrewd"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Values from the database

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640d94d8d9083914690976f5"
  },
  "result": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    9
  ]
}
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6416cd57ebd738fb8d1bb1d6"
  },
  "result": [
    3,
    4
  ]
}
```

And it turns out like this

Comment: `join()` is blocking the execution of the calling thread until its thread has finished. Besides, what you're doing in those `update_plot` functions will get absolutely **no** benefit from threading.

Comment: even without using multithreading, the chart still displays the entire array at once

Comment: Without knowing the data structure, we cannot really help you. It's even completely unclear if you're trying to use threading to allow some form of "pseudo-parallelism" because the amount of data is too big to process or just for animation purposes.